# Sonarqube - inclusions being ignored

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am simply trying to analyze all of the java files located inside the src directory, but I can't get this working.

The sonar-scanner configuration file I have added is :

```
sonar.projectKey=three
sonar.projectName=three
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources = C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/x/y/src
sonar.inclusions = C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/x/y/src/**/*.java
```

I have also tried brute forcing many combinations such as

```
sonar.projectKey=three
sonar.projectName=three
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources = C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/x/y/src
sonar.inclusions = src/**/*.java
```

I keep getting told when running that "39 files ignored by inclusion/exclusion patterns", why is it being ignored?? What am I missing here.

Also, how do the examples even work when starting with src/*, how does it even know what src they're referring to or where it is located?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things going on here

First, paths in your analysis properties should be relative to your project root. So, not `sonar.sources=C:/...` but (guessing here) `sonar.sources=y/src` or more probably `sonar.sources=src`. Why does this work? Because you `cd` into your project root before running analysis.

This path confusion probably explains why your inclusion isn't working. *However* you don't need to set an inclusion if you simply want to analyze the files in `src`; all you need to do is properly set your sources path & the analyzer will do the rest.

One last thing: your first three properties have no spaces around the `=`, but your paths do. To be safe, you should omit them, for:

```
sonar.projectKey=three
sonar.projectName=three  // note that this will default to key if omitted
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src
```